# Why is OnRampKit >> Monerium not working with Safes?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

Using **Monerium** provider of **OnRampKit** (which does not support EIP2612's `permit` function),  you get their own token (**$EURe**) deposited on your connected Safe address.

My question is, how can you use the tokens without being able to directly call `approve`? Am I missing something here?